# WPF Alternative for python

Tags: python, user-interface

Is there any alternative for WPF (windows presentation foundation) in python?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx#Programming_with_WPF

Comment: IronPyton is your thingy dawg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a list of [Python GUI Toolkits](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming).

Also, you can [use IronPython to work with WPF directly](http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2007/07/hello-wpf-in-ironpython.html).

Comment: IronPython is tha thing you're looking for, no question about it

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [pygtk](http://www.pygtk.org/) and [glade](http://glade.gnome.org/). [Here](http://www.learningpython.com/2006/05/07/creating-a-gui-using-pygtk-and-glade/) is a tutorial.

There is a long [list of alternatives](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) on the [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/FrontPage).

Answer (score 2):

Try [PyQt](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-qt/) which binds python to QT graphics library. There are some other links at the end of that article:

- Anygui
- PyGTK
- FXPy
- wxPython
- win32ui

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows and you want to use WPF (as opposed to an alternative), you can use it with [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=IronPython) - a .NET version of python.

Here's a quick example: http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2007/07/hello-wpf-in-ironpython.html